# Load portions of matrix into RAM

Tags: python, data-structures, microcontroller, micropython

I'm writing some image processing routines for a micro-controller that supports MicroPython. The bad news is that it only has 0.5 MB of RAM. This means that if I want to work with relatively big images/matrices like 256x256, I need to treat it as a collection of smaller matrices (e.g. 32x32) and perform the operation on them. Leaving at aside the fact of reconstructing the final output of the orignal (256x256) matrix from its (32x32) submatrices, I'd like to focus on how to do the loading/saving from/to disk (an SD card in this case) of this smaller matrices from a big image.

Given that intro, here is my question: Assuming I have a 256x256 on disk that I'd like to apply some operation onto (e.g. convolution), what's the most convenient way of storing that image so it's easy to load it into 32x32 image patches? I've seen there is a MicroPython implementation of the pickle module, is this a good idea for my problem?

Comment: Flash memory cycles are limited, I wouldn't use a flash card extensively as working space.

Comment: that's a good point. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question contains the answer - if you need to work with 32x32 tiles, the best format is that which represents your big image as a sequence of tiles (and e.g. not as one big 256x256 image, though reading tiles out of it is also not a rocket science and should be fairly trivial to code in MicroPython, though 32x32 tiles would be more efficient of course).

You don't describe the exact format of your images, but I wouldn't use pickle module for it, but store images as raw bytes and load them into array.array() objects (using inplace .readinto() operation).